# Activating a div when a certain element takes too long to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make a hidden div activate (or unhide) If a certain Div is taking longer than 30 seconds to completely load all elements within it?

I can't figure out a code.

Comment: Do you mean like an ajax call is taking too long to get the results back or the html in the div is so huge the browser is taking 30+seconds to render it?

Comment: Load what and how? Images? Content via AJAX?

Comment: @danny no. It's just a div with a number of images that are bigger than usual. But yes for some viewers it can take 30+ seconds to load them. I want to have a div appear above the images if this occurs

Comment: @WeDiamondFew Would something like this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached

Comment: Well actually it might, but wouldn't that mean I'd need to repeat the code for every single Img src?

Comment: You could put a page loader set to window.load so it only disappears after all the images are loaded, no matter how long the loading takes (the 30 secs doesn't matter in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML looks something like this

```
<body>
    <img src="...">
</body>
```

you could do something like this:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">slowTimer = setTimeout(function() { $("#slowLoadingDiv").show(); }, 30000)</script>;
    <img src="...">
    <script type= "text/javascript">clearTimeout(slowTimer);</script>
</body>
```

Basically, before your "slow loading" code, you start a timer, and when it fires you do something. After the DOM loads, you cancel said timer.

Comment: Yeah it's something similar to this. I'm making a gallery  for my school with bigger than usual images. Regardless of how long the images in the div take to load I don't want them be touched or changed. The plan is to have a div appear above the gallery with a button that says "optimize" if the images are loading too slow for the viewer. but I don't want the div to appear unless necessary